# Passing data from a table view controller to a another view controller contained within tab view?

Tags: ios, swift

So, As of right now what I understand about Swift is that in order to transition from one view to another the way to go about it is using segues. However, in my app I have a table view which shows a list of items where the user can interact with it and doing so will move the items to another view controller in my app, contained within a tab bar.

```
class JobCompletedTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    var jobsCompleted = [Job]()
    var jobsChosen = [Job]()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Share") { action, index in
            // Add data to the array created locally
            self.jobsChosen.append(self.jobsCompleted[indexPath.row])
        }

        share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        return [share]
    }
     // Need some sort of method to pass data into other view 
     //controller if tab button is clicked
}
```

The Table View that is embeded within a navigation controller and Tab Bar view controller.

```
class ChosenTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    var jobsChosen = [Job]()

    // Upon initalization of this view, this array should be populated with data passed from the above view controller
}
```

My initial thought on this problem was to simply create an array in the view controller that tracks user interaction with list items. Then add items that user interacted with to array. When user clicks on item in tabbar, instantiate the other table view controller which shows all items that user interacted with.

I would appreciate it if you would go into how I can actually instantiate an instance of the ChosenTableViewController class which will hold all the list of items user interacted with.

Storyboard, to give an idea of what My app looks like and how its contained
[image]

Comment: Its unclear which view controllers your referring to based on your diagram. Are you trying to go from prepare referral to jobs vc? Adding a prepared referral to the list of jobs? Is this stuff your persisting locally or pulling from a network?

Comment: Ah I appologize, I am trying to go from Jobs VC to Email VC by tapping on the tab below. The data is persisted locally, I will edit it to clarify

Comment: The best way to go about it is to use core data, realm, or whatever persistance method you are currently using, and add a Bool property to the Job Type with default value of false (ex. var selected = false). Whenever a user selects a row, you would change the value of the selected property and persist the new selection. Then when you go to e-mail vc, you would retrieve all Jobs where selected value == true. This removes passing data from vc to vc. I would write an answer but I can't give full example in code. Figure this can get you started in the mean time on an implementation

Comment: hmm,  appreciate the suggestion. However, the number of jobs will be very large compared to what would be passed into the e-mail vc. I expect only about a maximum of 3 such items in the email list compared to thousands upon thousands of items in the job VC. That dosent really sound like a feasible way to do it, If I would have to iterate through the entire list twice. Do you think theres another way to go about this problem?

Comment: if its only a few and you don't need to persist the selected ones beyond the current session, you can use a singleton with an array of the selected jobs. If you need to persist a small array of selected jobs you can also use NSUserDefaults. NSUserDefaults would require you to conform to NSCoder or convert them into Dictionary objects.

Comment: I see, thank you! Let me do a google search on singletons. However, I would still need a way to determine if the user has indeed clicked on the tab button. But as per your suggestion I will implement the singleton

Comment: lets go to private chat and I'll help you out, I don't want these comments to get too long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126986/discussion-between-justinm-and-edward-lim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they don't need to be persisted, the simplest solution would be to use a singleton that will hold the selected Jobs in an array that you can retrieve from the e-mail VC when it appears.

```
final class SelectedJobs {

static let shared = SelectedJobs()

var jobsArray = [Job]()
}
```

Then in the e-mail VC:

```
 class EmailVC: UIViewController {
    var selectedJobs = [Job]()

    override func viewWillApear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

         for job in SelectedJobs.shared.jobsArray {
         selectedJobs.append(job)
         }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
   }

}
```